# How does this createReadStream filter time values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, leveldb

I'm trying to understand the code from [this Github repo](https://github.com/substack/clocker/blob/master/bin/cmd.js) and I'm stuck with this particular code piece:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var minimist = require('minimist');
var level = require('level');
var strftime = require('strftime');
var through = require('through');
var editor = require('editor');
var stringify = require('json-stable-stringify');
var os = require('os');
var tmpdir = (os.tmpdir || os.tmpDir)();

var HOME = process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE;
var datadir = path.join(HOME, '.clocker');
mkdirp.sync(datadir);

var db = level(path.join(datadir, 'db'), { encoding: 'json' });

# [...]
# *SNIPP*
# [...]

    var s = db.createReadStream({
        gt: 'time!', lt: 'time!~',
        limit: 1, reverse: true
    });
```

I understand that this `createReadStream` gets some of the records from the database filtered according to that object literal passed to `createReadStream`.
What I don't understand is: what does `'time!'` and `'time!~'` do? They are string literals, so I guess they will tell the level engine to do something or to assume some value?

Sadly, I haven't found any documentation about this that could help me.

Could you please help me understand what's going on in this snippet?
Also, I'd be glad if you had links to documentations about those parameters (sadly, I don't know how to search for them).

Answer (score 0):

Think ASCII for a moment,

consider the string time! and time!~

If you look at
http://www.asciitable.com/

You will notice ~ is 126, and ! is 33

all nonspace special and alphanumeric ascii characters fall into the space between ! and ~, so the code really is just filtering between time! and time!~

e.g. timea timeb timec would fall into this range 
(EDIT: I had messed up which direction the equality was going, the ! should not be included in the matched strings)

Comment: sorry I didn't get back until now. Focused on another project in the meantime... I still don't get it. How does this help to filter for dates? And also: is this filtering technique a feature of js or leveldb?